# c# find certain strings of an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am making a proxy scraper program and i need to find the proxies in an array

Here is an example of what i want to get out of this line:

`document.write('77.237.138.51')`

I want to remove `document.write('" and "')` so it only shows the proxy

Here is my current code:

```
client.DownloadFile("http://www.gatherproxy.com/sockslist", "source.txt"); 
string [] lines = File.ReadAllLines("source.txt");
string start = "document.write('";
string end = "')";
```

Now how would I make it so where i can delete start and end and return the middle element (the proxy)

In reply to Domysee

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            client.DownloadFile("http://www.gatherproxy.com/sockslist", "source.txt");
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("source.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            string[] ipAddresses = lines.Select(l => Regex.Match(l, @"(\d+\.){3}\d+").Value).ToArray();
            i++;
            string[] port = lines.Select(l => Regex.Match(l, @"(\d+\.){3}\d+").Value).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(ipAddresses + ":" + port);
        }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: So source.txt contains lines in the format "document.write('11.111.111.11')" and you need "11.111.111.11" from it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Does your source document contain other lines that have IP addresses?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, it does and I want to retrieve them all

Comment: @Zezima - So you **also** want to retrieve IP address that **aren't** surrounded by `document.write('` & `')`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Every IP address is surrounded by document.write(' & ') I want to remove document.write(' & ') and display the IP address

Comment: @Zezima - Yes, but when I asked if there were other IP addresses in the document you said, "Yes, it does and I want to retrieve them all" - meaning you want them all regardless if they are surrounded by `document.Write` or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `Regex` for this purpose.

```
string[] ipAddresses = lines.Select(l => Regex.Match(l, @"(\d+\.){3}\d+").Value).ToArray();
```

The regex will extract the bit that corresponds to the ip address.

`ipAddresses` is an array of strings. If you concatenate it with another string (as you're doing in `Console.WriteLine(ipAddresses + ":" + port);`, its `ToString` method will be called, which is "System.String[]".

To output the ip addresses you have to iterate over the array.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("source.txt");
string[] ipAddresses = lines.Select(l => Regex.Match(l, @"(\d+\.){3}\d+").Value).ToArray();
for(int i = 0; i < ipAddresses.Length; i++){
    Console.WriteLine(ipAddresses[i]);
}
```

Comment: I just wouldn't reuse `lines`. Variables are cheap.

Comment: System.String[] is returning instead of the IP address. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Zezima How are you using the `ipAddresses` variable?

Comment: @Domysee http://prntscr.com/abfbof here's a screenshot of my code, also forgot to mention I am new to C#

Comment: @Zezima I cannot view the page, why dont you update your post with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("source.txt");

string[] ipAddresses = lines.Select(line => String.Join("", line.SkipWhile(c => c != '\'')
                                                                .Skip(1)
                                                                .TakeWhile(c => c != '\'')))
                            .ToArray();
```